# Tableau - Unable to replace data source in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using MongoDB connected to Tableau using ODBC drivers..

I have connected to databases on Mongo.. Now i want to replace the data source with other databases.. b

I have query from customer saying that they want to see the same visualizations even after changing the data source to other which have json with same data.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing a data source is rather simple. Add the query to the workbook - create an extract if needed - then return to a worksheet. Right-click on the data source's name and select "Replace data source...". This will give you a menu from which you choose which data source is to be used instead.

For other troubleshooting visit:
https://community.tableau.com/thread/151396

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.. But when i was trying to do the same.. replace datasource is not highlighted or not enabled to do so..